# When does a running Docker container run out of disk space?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I've read through so much documentation, and I'm still not sure how this really works. It's a bit of a Docker vs. VM question.

If I start a VM with a 2GB hard drive and fill its disk with files, I know it runs out after 2GB of files.

Does Docker work the same way? I would assume so. But from what I've read about "UnionFS" it seems like it *does not* run out of space.

So then why do Docker "volumes" exist? Is that automagically expanding Docker disk space transient in some way? Will the files I've saved inside of my Docker container disappear after a reboot? How about after restarting the container?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Docker's usage (1.12+) depends on the [Docker storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/) and possibly the physical file system in use.

**TL;DR** Storage will be shared between all containers and local volumes unless you are using the `devicemapper` storage driver or have set a limit via `docker run --storage-opt size=X` when running on the `zfs` or `btrfs` drivers. Docker 1.13+ also supports a quota size with `overlay2` on an `xfs` backed file system.

#### Containers

For all storage drivers, except `devicemapper`, the container and local volume storage is limited by the underlying file system hosting `/var/lib/docker` and it's subdirectories. A container can fill the shared file system and then other containers can't write any more.

When using the `devicemapper` driver, a default volume size of 100G is "thin allocated" for each container. The default size can be overridden with the daemon option [`--storage-opt dm.basesize` option](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19123) or set on a per container basis with `docker run --storage-opt size=2G`.

The same per container quota support is available for the [`zfs`](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/21946) and  [`btrfs`](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19651) drivers as both file systems provide simple built in support for creating volumes with a size or quota.

The [`overlay2` storage driver on xfs supporta per container quotas as of Docker 1.13](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/24771). This will probably be extended to ext4 when new 4.5+ kernels become standard/common and ext4 and xfs quotas share a common API.

#### Volumes

[Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/data-volumes) are separate from a container and can be viewed as a persistant storage area for an ephemeral container.

Volumes are stored separately from Docker storage, and have their own plugins for different backends. `local` is the default backend, which writes data to `/var/lib/docker/volumes` so is held outside of the containers storage and possible quota system.

Other [volume plugins](https://bitbucket.org/osallou/docker-plugin-zfs/src) could be used if you wanted to set per volume limits on a local file system that supports it.

Containers will keep their own file state over a container restart and reboot, until you [`docker rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/) the container. Files in a volume will survive a container removal and can be mounted on creation of the new container.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Raises another question for me though. Since it sounds like Docker is not going to run out of disk, any more than a non-Docker solution, then why NOT run a DB inside of a container? Performance?

Comment: The `aufs` and `overlay` storage drivers have a performance penalty as they are a layer on top of the native file system. For a db, mounting a `local` volume or host directory for the db data/logs should be ok as they use the native file system directly, but you would need to benchmark to be sure. It's kind of like running a DB on a VM, you're probably going to get better performance on metal but if benchmarking shows the impact is small then the ease of management might trump perf.